# Npm user authorization on macOS

Tags: node.js, npm, solidity, truffle, hardhat

I recently started using macOS, but it is difficult to understand the file structure of this system. While I could directly install Node.js and similar things on Windows, I came across something called root here. I installed node.js many times, but I always got an authorization error. Then I defined the file path `/usr/local/bin` as my user account. I'm having similar problems again.
**Do I need to make a different configuration when installing node.js on macOS?**

This is the directory where npm is currently installed: `/usr/local/bin`

And I can see that it is installed correctly with the version command in Terminal.

However, I get these kinds of errors when using testing tools such as hardhat and truffle.

If you could help with this situation, I would greatly appreciate it

```
dmrdvn@192 hello-hardhat % npm install --save-dev hardhat
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path /Users/dmrdvn/.npm/_cacache/index-v5/fc/e8/7cf98502e539fbf32814adcd761b1fa4ec1b1065dc514653244ef6cc9357
npm ERR! errno EACCES
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Your cache folder contains root-owned files, due to a bug in
npm ERR! previous versions of npm which has since been addressed.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! To permanently fix this problem, please run:
npm ERR!   sudo chown -R 501:20 "/Users/dmrdvn/.npm"
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: /Users/dmrdvn/.npm/_logs/2023-10-01T23_12_14_376Z-debug-0.log
dmrdvn@192 hello-hardhat %
```

Comment: You certainly don't need root (administrator) access to install and use Node.js on macOS. How exactly did you install it? Sounds like you've used `sudo npm ...` at some point which has created root owned files in your npm cache. One quick solution would be to use `sudo rm -r ~/.npm` to clear that out

Comment: The command you mentioned worked. 
I think after clearing the caches everything seems fine. Thank you 